# Точка после 0 в EditText

Tags: android, float, edittext

Есть **EditText**, в который вводится число. Надо чтоб если первым ввели 0, то после него автоматически ставилась точка, чтоб не была чисел типа 00145.
Сделал так:

```
if(String.valueOf(eText.getText().charAt(0)).equals("0") && eText.getText().toString().length()<2)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(eText.getText().toString()).insert(1, ".");
        eText.setText(sb.toString());
        eText.setSelection(eText.length());
        }
```

Но минус в том, что когда стираешь значение из **EditText** и доходишь до точки, то она не стирается(ну точнее ставится заново из-за условия). Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вставлять точку, только если ее забыли указать при вводе более одного символа.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(eText.getText().toString());
if(s.length() > 1){
    if(s.charAt(0) == '0' && s.charAt(1) != '.'){
        s.insert(1, '.');
    }
}
eText.setText(s.toString());
```

Так же стоит предусмотреть локализацию не все используют точку для отделения дробной части.

Comment: Зависает при начале ввода в EditText... И там разве должно быть не s.charAt(1) != '.', вместо charAt(0)?

Comment: Верно, поправил.

Comment: В моем примере были такие же зависания при s.lenght()>1, поэтому и заменил на s.lenght()<2. Так зависания пропали...

Comment: Если напишите `s.lenght()<2` получите ошибку: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 1,length 1`

Comment: Возможно ещё зависания связанны с тем, что этот код вставлен в TextWatcher в afterTextChanged...

Comment: Всё, разобрался, я забыл добавить _ignore. Вот окончательный код: if(_ignore)   return;  _ignore = true;  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(eText.getText().toString());  if(s.length() > 1){   if(s.charAt(0) == '0' && s.charAt(1) != '.'){    s.insert(1, '.');   }  }  eText.setText(s.toString());  eText.setSelection(eText.getText().toString().length());  _ignore = false;